# R- keep dataframe rows only if the row name is in a list

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with many columns, but the first column contains names.

I have a list of names.

I want to only keep rows of the dataframe if the first column's name is in my list.

For example, if I have this as my dataframe:

```
 names     birthday
 Alice     June
 Bob       May
 Eve       December
```

and I have this as my list:

```
 list_of_names <- c("Alice","Bob")
```

I want to get:

```
 names     birthday
 Alice     June
 Bob       May
```

I am thinking perhaps a for loop, like this:

```
for (i in list_of_names) {
  #if i is in df$names, append to new df?
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `%in%` operator will be helpful here

```
dd<-data.frame(names=c("Alice","Bob","Eve"), birthday=c("June","May","December"))
subset(dd, names %in% c("Alice","Bob"))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
newdf <- df[df$names %in% list_of_names,]
```

should do it, and maybe even

```
rownames(df) <- df$names
newdf <- df[list_of_names,]
```

Comment: yes, I realized that and was editing as you commented.  Thanks.